# Codeigniter: Call to a member function result_array() on a non-object caused by bad column?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlsrv

I'm having an issue in codeigniter to return a result set. When I'm avoiding 1 column in my select, the result is correct.
But when i want to include the column (description) then i get the error and my result-set is corrupt. Anyone knows how to solve this issue. The column has soms records with characters like &,'/...  I might think that this causes the problem.

some details:

```
'char_set' => 'UTF-8',
'dbcollat' => 'Latin1_General_100_CS_AS',
```

I already tried to change these parameters without success.

EDIT Code added:

get and get_by function.

```
public function get($id = NULL, $single = FALSE) {

    if($id != NULL){
        $this->db->where($this->_primary_key, $id);
        $method = 'row';
    }
    elseif($single == TRUE){
        $method = 'row';
    }
    else{
        $method = 'result';
    }

    if($_order_by != ''){
        if(!count($this->db->ar_orderby)){
            $this->db->order_by($this->_order_by);
        }

    }
    //$query = $this->db->query("Select Description from items WHERE Company = 'MINITFR'");

   // $array = $query->result_array();
   // return 'test';
   // var_dump($this->db->get_compiled_select($this->_table_name));
    return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->result_array();
  // return $this->db->get($this->_table_name)->$method();
}

public function get_by($where, $single = FALSE) {
    $this->db->where($where);   
    return $this->get(NULL,$single);
}
```

function in controller:

```
public function show_items(){

    $this->load->model('item_m');
    $this->data['ajax_req'] = TRUE;
    $where = "Company = '".$this->session->userdata('company')."'";
    $this->data['item_list'] = $this->item_m->get_by($where,FALSE);
    $this->load->view('pages/details/components/item_list', $this->data);
}
```

Comment: add your code as well

Comment: Add the code..otherwise it's not possible for people to help you

Comment: Add the code. It's not possible for people to help you without code

Comment: Sorry i've now added the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this one:

```
return $this->db->get('table_name')->result_array();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: I added the code above result_array() is not working.

Comment: yes, but I found some strange thing... if I change the length of the fields to shorter fields like varchar(500) -> varchar(50), he can query the results. but when I try to get all the columns he gives me back again this error. It has something to do with the length or to many data...

Comment: then change your datatype to text instead of varchar